# selecting more than one item in gridview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im  having a problem in my seats page can anyone help me with this., as you can see i already showed the seats using gridview but I'm having trouble making it selectable. I want the user to be able to select 1 or more seats or deselect it and then show their selected seats

this is what i want to achieve
[seat_selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz9lI.png)

thank you

my Seats Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Seats extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _SeatsState createState() => new _SeatsState();
}

class _SeatsState extends State<Seats> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff828EFB),
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 100,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text("Seats" , style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
    fontSize: 28,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color: Colors.white
  ),),
        titleSpacing: 6,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:
          Container(
                height: 420,
                width: 350,
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(25, 65, 1),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.pink,
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 0,
            offset: Offset(-7, 8), // changes position of shadow
          ),
    ],
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)
                  ),
                  
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
               transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 40, 1),
              child: Text("Screen")
            ),
            Container(
              width: 250,
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 50, 1),
              child: Divider(
                height: 10,
                color: Colors.pink,
                thickness: 3,

              ),
            ),
            Container(
                    transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 100, 1),

              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right:20),
                child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    crossAxisCount: 6,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    childAspectRatio: 1,
                    children: List.generate(seats.length, (index) {
                      return Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                          },
                          color: Color(0xff828EFB),
                          child: Text(
                            seats[index] , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                  
    ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 160, 1),
              child: Text("your selected seats are: ")
            )
          ],
        ),
        
      ),

    );
  }
}
List<String> seats = [
  'A1',
  'A2',
  'A3',
  'A4',
  'A5',
  'B1',
  'B2',
  'B3',
  'B4',
  'B5',
  'C1',
  'C2',
  'C3',
  'C4',
  'D1',
  'D2',
  'D3',
  'D4',
  'D5',
  'E1',
  'E2',
  'E3',
  'E4',
  'E5',
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create List of seats index:

```
List<int> _selectedItems = List();
```

And add these codes to `RaisedButton‍ -> onPressed()` and change the color of the item accordingly:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _selectedItems.contains(index) ? _selectedItems.remove(index) : _selectedItems.add(index);
    });
  },
  color: _selectedItems.contains(index) ? Colors.lightGreen : Color(0xff828EFB),
  child: Text(
    seats[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
  ),
),
```

Now everywhere you want can use this selected list.

**Update**

for showing selected seats to user, create String field like:

```
String _selectedSeatsText = "Nothing";
```

and set its to your Text :

```
Container(
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 160, 1),
  child: Text("your selected seats are: $_selectedSeatsText "),
)
```

and finaly use this method for change text:

```
void getSelectedSeats() {
  _selectedSeatsText = "";
  _selectedItems.forEach((element) {
    if (_selectedSeatsText != "") _selectedSeatsText += " , ";
    _selectedSeatsText += (seats[element]);
  });
}
```

I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: thank you it worked!! but when i used child: Text("your selected seats are:" + "$_selectedItems") it shows as the numbers not what in my list as A1 , A2 ,A3.... how can I change that?

Comment: I updated my post and added `printSelectedSeats` to show items. also you can store seat String item (A1,A2,...) in `_selectedItems`. "List<String> _selectedItems = List();"

Comment: If it worked and useful for you, choose it as the correct answer. thanks :)

Comment: i update my post for your request. Is this what you want?